# Scrollbar grays out on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I use

```
 my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

my scrollbar goes gray.

relevant code:

```
 window.geometry("1550x500")
    main_frame = Frame(window, background="blue")
    main_frame.grid(sticky="news")
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky='news')

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame, command=my_canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky="ns")

    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

    def edit_password():
        text1.config(state="normal")
        text2.config(state="normal")
        text3.config(state="normal")
        text4.config(state="normal")

    vault_label = tk.Label(my_canvas, text="Welcome to your password vault", font=("Time New Roman", 20))
    vault_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

    add_button = tk.Button(my_canvas, text="Add new info", command=add_entry)
    add_button.grid(column=0, padx=8)

    website_label = tk.Label(my_canvas, text="Website")
    website_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=80)

    username_label = tk.Label(my_canvas, text="Username")
    username_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=80, pady=8)

    password_label = tk.Label(my_canvas, text="Password")
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=80)

    days_password_is_good_for = tk.Label(my_canvas, text="Days password is good for")
    days_password_is_good_for.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=80)
```

I have tried following tutorials, however; they mostly seem to use the .pack method. I need to use the .grid method.

Comment: There is nothing in the canvas, so what do you expect the result of `my_canvas.bbox("all")` (which is used for the `scrollregion` option)?

Comment: I will update the relevant code to show I have items in the canvas

Comment: Widgets added into canvas by `.grid(...)` are not considered as *canvas items*, so the result of `.bbox("all")` will not be changed.  You need to create a frame and add it to the canvas using `my_canvas.create_window(...)` and then add those widgets into that frame.  Also you need to bind `<Configure>` on that frame and update the `scrollregion` option inside the event callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you be able to post an example of how to do that using my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that widgets added into a canvas using `.grid(...)` will not be considered as *canvas items*, so the result of `my_canvas.bbox("all")` will not be affected.

You need to create a frame and add it into the canvas using `my_canvas.create_window(...)`, and then add those widgets into that frame.  Also you need to bind `<Configure>` event on that frame and update the `scrollregion` of the canvas inside the event callback.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

#window.geometry("1550x500")

main_frame = tk.Frame(window, background="blue")
main_frame.grid(sticky="news")

my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky='news')

# changed orientation to horizontal
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient="horizontal", command=my_canvas.xview)
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=9, sticky="ew")

my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

def add_entry():
    pass

# create a frame for other widgets
my_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas, bd=1, relief="solid")
my_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=my_frame, anchor="nw")

vault_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Welcome to your password vault", font=("Time New Roman", 20))
vault_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

add_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Add new info", command=add_entry)
add_button.grid(column=0, padx=8)

website_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Website")
website_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=80)

username_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Username")
username_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=80, pady=8)

password_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=80)

days_password_is_good_for = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Days password is good for")
days_password_is_good_for.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=80)

my_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you again. Any tips on how to dynamically expand my_frame so I can view everything?

Comment: Bind `<Configure>` event on `my_canvas` and resize `my_frame` inside the event callback.  Note that you need the *item ID* returned by `my_canvas.create_window(...)`.